# How to convert .stl files into a .x3d file using Java / Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, x3d

I want to convert .stl files to a .x3d file so that it can be used by HTML5 supported browser. I have figured out way to display x3d in HTML5 but struggling with converting .stl files to .x3d format using either Java or Javascript. Please help.

Comment: Check https://openjscad.org/, that page can receive stl and x3d files and it is open source

Comment: Descriptions and links for numerous tools for X3D import/export/conversion are maintained at [X3D Resources: Conversions and Translation Tools](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html#Conversions)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) by using the tools provided by [jscad](https://github.com/jscad):

```
const stlDeSerializer = require('@jscad/stl-deserializer');
const x3dSerializer = require('@jscad/x3d-serializer');

const rawData = fs.readFileSync('PATH/TO/file.stl');
const csgData = stlDeSerializer(rawData);
const x3dData = x3dSerializer(csgData);
```

Comment: Is there also a simple way of writing the file out? Thanks in advance.